# ng-options with dynamic default value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this structure in javascript

```
$scope.prefixes = [
  {'id': 'Mr', 'name': 'Mr.'},
  {'id': 'Mrs', 'name': 'Mrs.'}                
];
```

and I get if my user is Mr or Mrs like so

```
JSON.parse(localStorageService.get("user")).prefix.
```

according to data I get when user logs in. So user's prefix is always dynamic.

This is my idea of getting if a user is a Mr or a Mrs, putting it in a scope var and then use that scope var in HTML to set a default value for a select tag

```
 $scope.prefixes = [
   {'id': 'Mr', 'name': 'Mr.'},
   {'id': 'Mrs', 'name': 'Mrs.'}                
 ];


  $scope.readPrefixesInit;

  for (i = 0; i < $scope.prefixes.length; i++) { 
     //if dynamic is equal with one of the ids, get the name
     if ($scope.prefixes[i].id == JSON.parse(localStorageService.get("user")).prefix){
        $scope.readPrefixesInit = $scope.prefixes[i].name;                                                          
      }
 }
```

and then in HTML

```
  <select required autofocus class="form-control"     
        ng-model="prefix" 
        ng-init="prefix =  {{ readPrefixesInit }}"
        ng-options="f.id as f.name for f in prefixes">          
        <option value="">Select Prefix</option>  
  </select>
```

This is not working.

I get this error `Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 12 of the expression [prefix =  {{ readPrefixesInit }}] starting at [{ readPrefixesInit }}].`

I get my dropdown but has no value pre-selected.

How do I fix this? 
Thanks

Comment: where do you define "readPrefixes"? I only see a  "prefixes" array in your code

Comment: @chris Sorry for that and thank you for he correction.  I edit my OP.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your HTML part. The line:

```
ng-init="prefix =  {{ readPrefixesInit }}"
```

should be:

```
ng-init="prefix = readPrefixesInit"
```

In fact you do not need the intermediate `readPrefixesInit` variable and can use `prefix` instead.

JS:

```
$scope.prefixes = [
  {'id': 'Mr', 'name': 'Mr.'},
  {'id': 'Mrs', 'name': 'Mrs.'}                
];

$scope.prefix = null;

for (i = 0; i < $scope.prefixes.length; i++) { 
    //if dynamic is equal with one of the ids, get the name
    if ($scope.prefixes[i].id == JSON.parse(localStorageService.get("user")).prefix) {
        $scope.prefix = $scope.prefixes[i].name;                                                          
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<select required autofocus class="form-control"     
      ng-model="prefix" 
      ng-options="f.id as f.name for f in prefixes">          
    <option value="">Select Prefix</option>  
</select>
```

[Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/MihhHz?p=preview) for demo.